# If $f$ is differentiable on an interval and $f'(x)<0$, then $f$ is strictly decreasing.

Tags: real-analysis

$f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ with $f'(x) \lt 0$, prove that $f$ is strictly decreasing.
I'm not really sure how to start so any help would be much appreciated! Thank you! 
EDIT : Could I use the following
$\lim\limits_{x \to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\lt0$ implies $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\lt0$

Comment: Use the mean value theorem,https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_1,x_2\in [a,b]$ and $x_1<x_2$. Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, by mean value theorem, there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that
$$
\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}=f'(c)
$$
and between $x_1$ and $x_2$. Since $f'(c)<0$ and $x_2-x_1 > 0$, we get $f(x_2)-f(x_1) < 0$.